# My download speed is stuck at 10MB

Tags: networking, internet-speed

I have 70MB connection and when I check on fast.com, it shows 65-70MB. But when I download any files, it is limited to 10-11MB/s. It is like it can go up but some component is limiting it. How can I figure out what is the bottleneck? In connection settings I see following -

[image]

I also changed following settings -

[image]

Comment: Please check your units. Line speeds are advertised in mega**bits** per second - mb/s or mbps - whereas your computer may be measuring in Mega**bytes** per second. 11MB/s is about 88mbps.

Comment: @Tetsujin Does marketing really use mb/s? Technically M- is mega-, m- is milli-.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I'd never be surprised at what they pretend are 'real units' in advertising, tbh. There is very little consistency right across the board. There can be no consensus on mega vs milli, because we quickly run out of varieties of the letter `m` You could take a swing with mu µ but the consumer is not going to have a clue. The UK does tend to use mbps but even those two pictures from Microsoft show no real consistency. Consumer speed in Mbps [which to me is bizarre], NIC in Gbps… how is the average 'man in the street' ever going to grasp the differences.

Comment: 100 Mbps on the network just about equals 10 MBps.

Comment: @harrymc, theoretically its 12.5MB/s, but in reality, you are quite correct, 10-11MB/s is generally maxing 100Mb/s bandwidth out.

Comment: @FrankThomas: These numbers relate to the naked payload data that's being transmitted. In reality, there are more bits being exchanged that are not counted because they're not part of the payload data. Dividing by 10, rather than by 8, is safer.

Comment: @FrankThomas "there can be no such thing as a millibit" – Sure it can, note we're talking "per second". 88 mbps (millibits per second) is about 5 bits per minute. Is 5 bits per minute impossible? 0.1 people per square kilometre does not mean someone has been dismembered. Similarly 88 millibits per second does not imply something smaller than one bit has ever been transferred.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, good point, I can't fault your logic.

Comment: This makes much sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the download *must* limit speed at their end *per* connection, or one user could prevent all others from accessing the site by using all available bandwidth.

You can test that, in some cases, with a multi-threaded download manager, e.g., [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/). As with any software, before installing or using, check the download at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to avoid malware.

Also, as mentioned in comment, MB ≠ Mb. As a side-note, the k prefix is interpreted as 1,000 **or** 1,024, and the M prefix as 1,000,000 **or** 1,048,576, to confuse the issue a bit (1/8 byte) more.

Comment: Your first paragraph is misleading because it makes it sound like you're talking about arbitrary rate caps. Servers don't cap bandwidth per connection, they just use algorithms that promote fairness. So if only a single download is happening, it gets all the bandwidth (if the client and the network in between have the capacity to) so none goes to waste. But if say 10 downloads are happening simultaneously, each gets roughly 1/10th of the bandwidth. If one of those stalls due to a network hiccup, the other 9 each get roughly 1/9th of the bandwidth until the stalled connection gets unstuck.